# Prevent Glassfish from using its own versions of libraries instead of those in a project

Tags: java, glassfish, pom.xml, glassfish-4

Glassfish has whole bunch of third-side libraries stored in its `modules` directory. To my surprise, if my project uses a library which is present there, Glassfish will provide it from there, instead of the right version I have packed-in in my WAR file.

This leads to a number of errors. For example, I use `jackson-datatype-joda` version 2.6.3, which requires `jackson-databind` with same version, and it is included in my project. But Glassfish replaces that package with version 2.3.2, which leads to [this issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/issues/57).

How can I prevent Glassfish (4.1) from replacing the libraries I use with another versions?

Answer (score 5):

Add a glassfish-web.xml file to your WEB-INF directory containing something like,

```
<glassfish-web-app>
  <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This will ensure classes are loaded from your war before the server classpath

Comment: I tried it and I on deploying I get: `Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension
`, then stacktrace: something with org.glassfish.grizzly, `Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:91)`

Comment: @MikhailBatcer did you solve your issue? I am fighting with the same thing.

Comment: @AngelAvila If I remember correctly, I had to rename conflicting old libraries in Glassfish `modules` directory adding `.bak` in the end (or smth like that to backup them. Maybe moving to `bak` folder is better), and then put there libraries with versions I needed. New libraries should have exactly the same names as old ones.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer not really a solution, but a work-around I would say

Comment: @ErdincAy I was too lazy and lacking time to post a bug report. Probably that would give a real solution.